# around_action in rails with passing arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I call `around_action` in Rails that accepts arguments?

```
around_action only: [:follow] do
 set_follow_source(@source)
end

def set_follow_source
  puts 'before'
  yield
  puts 'after'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to clarify your question. Who or what component exactly should set this argument?

In case *you* want to create some DSL so as to set an argument beforehand for around action, you can do something like that:

```
def self.say_hello_to(name)
  lambda do |controller, block|
    hello name, &block
  end
end

around_action say_hello_to('smith'), only: :index

def index
end

private

def hello(name, &block)
  puts 'hello'
  yield
  puts name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it already accepts some arguments, you can access controller instance as argument in the action filter callback,
like this:

```
around_action only: [:follow] do |controller, block|
  controller.send(:any_method); 
  block.call # or yield
end
```

looks like it's okay to do this kind of things in Rails,
you can find similar example in [Rails docs paragraph 8.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and here is an example from [Rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L633):

```rb
 set_callback :save, :around, ->(r, block) { stuff; result = block.call; stuff }
```

so you just need to pass the block to your around filter like that:

```
around_action only: [:follow] do |_, blk|
 set_follow_source(@source, &blk)
end

def set_follow_source
   puts 'before'
   yield
   puts 'after'
end
```